# Monotonic convergence of Newton's method for boundary value problems

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, elliptic-pde

I’m interested in solving nonlinear elliptic boundary value problems of the type
$$
-a\Delta u + f(u) = 0,
$$
$$
u|_\Gamma = u_0
$$
by Newton’s method when its convergence is global and monotonic.
Could you advice some references concerning this problem, containing proofs of global convergence?

Newton's method takes the form
$$
-a\Delta u + f(\widetilde u) + f'(\widetilde u)(u - \widetilde u) = 0
$$
where $\widetilde u$ is the previous approximation for the solution.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20147, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359092. Please don't do that.